# Draw dynamically in Console with Java

Tags: java, console, maze, println

I'm trying to create some sort of maze, and I want to print de map to show every room in it.
Here's the code :

```
    public void drawMap(){
    String result=R[0][0].drawSalle();

    Salle_test currentRoom = R[0][0];
    Salle_test initialRoom;
    while (currentRoom!=R[1][2]){
        initialRoom = currentRoom;
            Direction d = currentRoom.getDirectionExit();
            currentRoom = currentRoom.getExit(d);
            if(currentRoom!=initialRoom)
                if (d.getName().equals("est"))
                    result+="\n\t"+currentRoom.drawSalle();
                else if (d.getName().equals("sud"))
                    result+="\n" + currentRoom.drawSalle();
    }                   
    while (currentRoom!=R[1][2]);
    //System.out.println(result);
}
```

In here, the starting room is R[0][0] and the last one is R[1][2]. 
`getExit(d)` and `getDirectionExit()` give respectively the direction of the direction of the exit, and the room at this place.

`drawSalle()` is supposed to retrun this as a string

---

### |   |

something like that. I want my method to draw this squares depending on the exits. For exemple if it's EAST I want it to add a square next to this one.

But apparently when I do result+=currentRoom.drawSalle() it adds the string at the bottom end of the previous square.

Help please !

Comment: you don't do `result+=currentRoom.drawSalle()`, you wrote `result+="\n\t"+currentRoom.drawSalle()` `\n` makes you go to the next line

Comment: Would you share the rest of your code? So that one can copy and paste it to an IDE of their liking :)